# How to align text within rcases environment?

Tags: math-mode, align

I am writing a code for an optimisation problem, which I have included below. I am trying to align the text "such that" with the first row of the constraints (starting with x_13). At present, it aligns with x_11. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\smash[b]{\underset{x_{ij}}{\textnormal{minimise}}} \quad 
&4x_{11}++\gamma(\theta)\\
&+2x_{22}+11x_{21}+13x_{77}\\
&+2x_{11}+9x_{31}+13x_{42}\\
\text{such that}\quad
 &\begin{rcases}
    x_{13}+x_{22}+x_{43}+x_{77}\leq 1, \ \\
    x_{11}+x_{22}+x_{15}+x_{33}\leq 5, \ \\    
    x_{39}+x_{30}+x_{38}+x_{39}\leq 45, \ \\ 
      \end{rcases} (\text{strong constraints}) \\
      &\begin{rcases}
    x_{19}+x_{01}+x_{11}\geq 4, \ \\ 
    x_{46}+x_{23}+x_{42}\geq 19, \ \\ 
    x_{10}+x_{24}+x_{33}\geq 17, \ \\ 
    \end{rcases} (\text{weak constraints}) \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the requitement, but is `&\text{such that} \\\ ` what you are looking for?  If you want it vertically aligned, you can use `\mathllap{\text{such that} \quad}` _inside_ the first `rcases`.

Comment: @PeterGrill Yes, that worked perfectly. It shifted `\text{such that}` up by one line.

Comment: I suppose `\shortintertext{such that}` (mathtools) takes up too much space.